# how to detect the button touched on uitableViewCell and changed the BG image of that button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm implementing an application in which i have UIButton on every cell, this button adds particular event to user's favorite and clicking again on that image it removes that event from user's favorite. i want to detect on which cell user has pressed that button and want to  change background image according to that.

[image: the circles in the image are uiButton]
Here is my code (what i've tried.)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            }
        uncheckButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        appDelegate.setValue = 0;
            [uncheckButton setFrame:CGRectMake (3, 25, 30, 30)];
            [uncheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [uncheckButton setSelected:NO];
            [uncheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(uncheckedButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell addSubview:uncheckButton];

        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
            return cell;

        }
-(IBAction)uncheckedButtonClicked:(id)sender
{

    if(appDelegate.setValue ==0)
    {
        appDelegate.setValue =1;
        [uncheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(uncheckedButtonClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [uncheckButton setFrame:CGRectMake(3, 25, 30, 30)];
        [uncheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] ;
        NetworkStatus netWorkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus] ;
        if (netWorkStatus == ReachableViaWWAN || netWorkStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
        {

                [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.user_id);
                Communication *objCommunication = [[Communication alloc] init];
                objCommunication.delegate = self;
                [objCommunication setServiceFor:@"My_Agenda_add"];

                NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/join_session",BASE_URL]];
                NSString *body = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@&session_id=%@",[appDelegate.user_id objectAtIndex:0],[[self.globalSessionArray valueForKey:@"_id"]valueForKey:@"$id"]];
                [objCommunication makeAsynchronousRequestWithUrl:url withBodyString:body andWithMethod:@"POST"];objCommunication = nil;

        }

        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:app_name message:network_connectivity delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }

    else if(appDelegate.setValue)
    {
        appDelegate.setValue = 0;
        [uncheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(uncheckedButtonClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [uncheckButton setFrame:CGRectMake(3, 25, 30, 30)];
        [uncheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] ;
        NetworkStatus netWorkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus] ;
        if (netWorkStatus == ReachableViaWWAN || netWorkStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
        {
                [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.user_id);
                Communication *objCommunication = [[Communication alloc] init];
                objCommunication.delegate = self;
                [objCommunication setServiceFor:@"My_Agenda_remove"];
                NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/unjoin_session",BASE_URL]];
                NSString *body = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@&session_id=%@",[appDelegate.user_id objectAtIndex:0],[[self.globalSessionArray valueForKey:@"_id"]valueForKey:@"$id"]];
                [objCommunication makeAsynchronousRequestWithUrl:url withBodyString:body andWithMethod:@"POST"];objCommunication = nil;

        }

        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:app_name message:network_connectivity delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }



    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] ;
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);

    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.agendaTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell addSubview:uncheckButton];
    [self.agendaTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyFeedCell";
NotificationCellView *cell = (NotificationCellView *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NotificationCellView" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (NotificationCellView *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
zNotification *notifiItem=(zNotification *)[notificationData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.Name.text = notifiItem.userName;
cell.clipImage.hidden= !notifiItem.hasFile;
[cell.clipImage addTarget:self action:@selector(viewFiles:) forControlEvents:
 UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.clipImage.tag=indexPath.row+100000;
cell.leftImg.hidden=YES;
cell.left.hidden=YES;
cell.centerImg.hidden=YES;
cell.center.hidden=YES;
//cell.right.hidden=YES;
//cell.rightImg.hidden=YES;
[cell.right addTarget:self action:@selector(wall_Followup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.right.tag = 1100+indexPath.row;
if(notifiItem.Type==0)
{

    [cell.right setTitle:@"Reply" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else
{

    [cell.center setTitle:@"Followup" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
switch (notifiItem.Type) {
    case 0:
        cell.tag.text=@"New Followup";
        [cell.userImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",notifiItem.userImg]]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.tag.text=@"New Task";
        [cell.userImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",notifiItem.userImg]]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        cell.centerImg.hidden=NO;
        cell.center.hidden=NO;
        [cell.center setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.centerImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Done.png"]];
        [cell.center addTarget:self action:@selector(doneTask:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.center.tag=1200+indexPath.row;
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.tag.text=@"New Member";
        [cell.userImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",notifiItem.userImg]]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        break;
    case 3:
        cell.tag.text=@"Task Reminder";
        [cell.userImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"attention.png"]];
        cell.Name.text = @"Attention";
        cell.centerImg.hidden=NO;
        cell.center.hidden=NO;
        [cell.center setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.centerImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Done.png"]];
        [cell.center addTarget:self action:@selector(doneTask:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.center.tag=1200+indexPath.row;
        break;
    case 4:
        cell.tag.text=@"New File";
        [cell.userImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",notifiItem.userImg]]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        break;
    case 5:
        cell.tag.text=@"Task Completed";
        [cell.userImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"attention.png"]];
        cell.Name.text = @"Attention";
        cell.centerImg.hidden=NO;
        cell.center.hidden=NO;
        [cell.center setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.centerImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete.png"]];
        [cell.center addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteTask:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        /*cell.leftImg.hidden=NO;
        cell.left.hidden=NO;
        [cell.left setTitle:@"Reassign" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.leftImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"re_Asign2.png"]];
        [cell.left addTarget:self action:@selector(reAssign:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];*/
        break;
    case 6:
        cell.tag.text=@"Task Deleted";
        [cell.userImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"attention.png"]];
        cell.Name.text = @"Attention";
        break;
    case 7:
        cell.tag.text=@"Group Deleted";
        [cell.userImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"attention.png"]];
        cell.Name.text = @"Attention";
        break;
    case 8:
        cell.tag.text=@"Group Invitation";
        [cell.userImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"groupInv.png"]];
        cell.Name.text = @"Invitation";
        cell.centerImg.hidden=NO;
        cell.center.hidden=NO;
        [cell.center setTitle:@"Join" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.center.tag = 1000+indexPath.row;
        [cell.centerImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"join.png"]];
        [cell.center addTarget:self action:@selector(joinGroup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}


cell.Details.text=notifiItem.MSG;
cell.date.text=notifiItem.date;//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",notifiItem.Type];//notifiItem.date;

cell.groupName.text = notifiItem.group.title;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
if (!notifiItem.isChecked) {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    float whiteFloat[4] = {1.0, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0};
    CGColorRef white = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, whiteFloat);
    cell.detailBox.layer.shadowColor=[[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    cell.shade.layer.backgroundColor=white;
}else
{
    //CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    //float whiteFloat[4] = {0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0};
    //CGColorRef white = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, whiteFloat);
    cell.detailBox.layer.shadowColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
}
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}


    - (IBAction)doneTask:(id)sender
    {
    UIButton *b=(UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d",b.tag);
    [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   zNotification *n=notificationData[b.tag-1200];
}
```

Hey 
this is quick example from one of my projects
here is important case 3: code is complecated
but you can use tag of button to assign row number off cell 1200 i added b/c
there are more then one button in same cell so for button A 1200 and button B 1300 and when i call
function I remove 1200 or 1300 accordingly and doneTask function simply cast button to UIButton and get row number from tag and assign background image

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this is creating a UITableViewCell subclass that handles the uncheckButtonClicked action.  self will remain the target, and so it's always being handled by the correct cell.

Another option is to have an NSDictionary on the view controller level that keeps track of UIButton/UITableViewCell pairs.  You can query the dictionary for the appropriate UITableViewCell that way.

Yet another option is to query the UIButton for it's superview, which will be the correct UITableViewCell.

```
-(IBAction)uncheckedButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[button superview];
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you explain your third way of doing by editing little bit of my code.? and is it possible if i try to attempt it by using the 'tag' property.?

Comment: I would look at Dima's answer first to address some of the more pressing issues with your code.  You cannot use tag because you are going the other way, trying to get a superview not a subview.  Probably safer to use the NSDictionary route.

Comment: See my updated answer for sample code on one way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code:

1. You are adding a new button subview to the cell every time it is updated, which is causing a leak because you are not reusing the old button. Instead, you should add the button once in the initialization code only, and give it a tag that you can use to access the button when getting a reused cell.
2. Based on your description, you want to have both a checked and unchecked case but only seem to have one. To solve this you could have an if/else statement in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that sets the image of the button to the correct one based on the model status.

hundredth's answer has a good suggestion which is to use some sort of model to keep track of which cell a button came from. An NSMutableDictionary would work well here. I would recommend against grabbing the superview of the button to get the cell it came from. Trying to get a model out of the view is bad practice and can lead to problems down the line.

Sample code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    UIButton *checkButton;
    static const NSInteger kCheckButtonTag = 1;
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        checkButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake (3, 25, 30, 30)];
        [checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkedButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        checkButton.tag = kCheckButtonTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:uncheckButton];
    }
    else
    {
        checkButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kCheckButtonTag];
    }


    if(model is unchecked) // replace with correct condition
        [checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [checkButton setImage:CHECKED_IMAGE_GOES_HERE forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // replace with your checked image

    // assuming buttonToModelDictionary is an initialized ivar NSMutableDictionary
    buttonToModelDictionary[checkButton] = YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT_GOES_HERE;
    return cell;

}

- (void) checkButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    (UIButton *)button = (UIButton *)sender;
    YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT_GOES_HERE = buttonToModelDictionary[button];

    // do whatever you need to update the model here, then call [self.tableView reloadData] OR [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths...] if you can gather the row using the model object, which you should be able to do.
}
```

Comment: ya i realize the issue with code.. i'll correct that but can you provide me some sort of link or tutorial where i can just check that how to handle these things with NSMutableDictionary.?

Comment: i'll try with this way and will let you know.